# Oracle19c -Create Role User Under the Tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, oracle18c, oracle19c

Hello How I can Create Roles with

`ReadOnly(Select any Tables under the tablespace)`

And

`InsertUpdateRoleOnly(To insert and update Data ,not delete)`

Under My tablespace with local access this users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are owned by *someone*. The owner grants privileges to other users or to roles; in your case, it'll be a role. As the role doesn't depend on a *tablespace* (you mentioned), you'd create it as simple as

```
create role r_read_only;
```

Then, the owner would grant `SELECT` privilege on its tables to that role, e.g.

```
grant select on emp  to r_read_only;
grant select on dept to r_read_only;
```

Such a role would be granted to other users, e.g.

```
grant r_read_only to littlefoot;
```

and user `littlefoot` will be able to select from those tables.

---

The same goes for your another role, no difference:

```
create role r_upd_ins;
grant insert, update on emp to r_upd_ins;
grant r_upd_ins to bigfoot;
```

Comment: create role r_read_only; 
Error starting at line : 15 in command -
 create role r_read_only
Error report -
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name
65096. 00000 -  "invalid common user or role name"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to create a common user or role with a name
           that was not valid for common users or roles. In addition to the
           usual rules for user and role names, common user and role names
           must consist only of ASCII characters, and must contain the prefix
           specified in common_user_prefix parameter.

Comment: thanks a lot for answer my question but i got error from-> create role r_read_only; user i use is sys and try with sys as sysdba , sys as sysoper but same result

Comment: That's, I presume, because you're on e.g. 19c. In that case, `create role c##_r_read_only` - use default prefix `c##_` (unless you set it differently).

Comment: unless you set it differently?

Answer (score 0):

Privileges cannot be granted at the tablespace level. You must grant privileges to specific tables. e.g:

```
create role read_data_role;
grant select on [owner].[table_name] to read_data_role;

create role update_data_role;
grant insert, update on [owner].[table_name] to update_data_role;

grant read_data_role, update_data_role to [username];
```